# Restoring auto renewable subscription giving "transaction.originalTransaction.transactionIdentifier" nil

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

Trying to restore the auto renewable in app after purchasing the transaction, it is giving nil in

```
 "transaction.originalTransaction.transactionIdentifier"
```

Why i am not able to restore after successful purchasing the subscription.
Please guide.